# Change a Segmented Control by Buttons

Tags: ios7, xcode5, objective-c-blocks

I need four buttons besides a four Labels instead of a Segmented Control with 4 buttons in the bottom of the VC. This is the code for the Segmented Control, I don't know how to set a button to activate the label to be populated by the datePicker. Any help is appreciated.

```
- (IBAction)didChangeDate:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

NSString *formattedDate = [formatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];

switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        _outLabel.text = formattedDate;
        outTime = self.datePicker.date;
        break;
    case 1:
        _inLabel.text = formattedDate;
        inTime = self.datePicker.date;
        break;
    case 2:
        _offLabel.text = formattedDate;
        offTime = self.datePicker.date;
        break;
    case 3:
        _onLabel.text = formattedDate;
        onTime = self.datePicker.date;
    default:
        break;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Button with Tag

```
  [_buttonOne setTag:0];
  [_buttonTwo setTag:1];
  [_buttonThree setTag:2];
  [_buttonFour setTag:3];
```

Then you can add a single IBAction selector, bind selector with buttons:

```
 - (IBAction)buttonSelector:(UIButton *)sender;
```

Use the above switch-case to do conditional selection

```
switch ([sender tag]) {
    case 0:
        _outLabel.text = formattedDate;
        outTime = self.datePicker.date;
        break;
    case 1:
        _inLabel.text = formattedDate;
        inTime = self.datePicker.date;
        break;
    case 2:
        _offLabel.text = formattedDate;
        offTime = self.datePicker.date;
        break;
    case 3:
        _onLabel.text = formattedDate;
        onTime = self.datePicker.date;
    default:
        break;
}
```

You can also add code for select/Deselect in the above switch-case.

Hope it helps.:)

Comment: Hi Meet, I think it will work but I am doing something wrong, I set one IBAction and drag the 4 buttons with Tags to the same IBAction, I am getting 4 errors of use of undeclared identifier FormattedDate :( I just add the first block of code on top of the old one, can you please take a look?

Comment: Please change the line "NSString *formattedDate = [formatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];" to "NSString *formattedDate = [formatter stringFromDate:sender.date];"